# How do you extract elements beside sub-elements from a list in R?

Tags: r, list

I would like to extract sub elements together with elements from a list into a data frame. Given this list:

```
list <- list(
  list(name="A",params=list(param_1=5, param_2=list(param_2_1=10,param_2_2=11))),
  list(name="B",params=list(param_1=6, param_2=list(param_2_1=12,param_2_2=13)))
)
```

I would like to get this dataframe:

```
dataframe <- data.frame(name=c("A","B"),param_1=c(5,6), param_2_2=c(11,13))
```

How do I get from the `list` to the `dataframe`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given

```
List <- list(
  list(name="A",params=list(param_1=5, param_2=list(param_2_1=10,param_2_2=11))),
  list(name="B",params=list(param_1=6, param_2=list(param_2_1=12,param_2_2=13)))
)
```

then

```
> data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(List,unlist)))
  name params.param_1 params.param_2.param_2_1 params.param_2.param_2_2
1    A              5                       10                       11
2    B              6                       12                       13
```

Comment: Try `as.data.frame(t(sapply(List, unlist)))`, it's a little faster and more succinct. +1 though.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `purrr`'s `map_dfr`/`map_df` :

```
purrr::map_dfr(list, as.data.frame)
#purrr::map_df(list, as.data.frame)

#  name params.param_1 params.param_2.param_2_1 params.param_2.param_2_2
#1    A              5                       10                       11
#2    B              6                       12                       13
```